# How to integrate tf.data.dataset with rayTune for distributed training

Tags: python, tensorflow, ray, ray-tune, petastorm

Using tensorflow-cpu==2.9.3, petastorm==0.12.1 on python 3.7

I've created tf.data.Dataset using petastorm for train and validation dataset.

- ds_train (DatasetV1Adapter; think this is old version of tf.data.dataset)
- ds_valid (DatasetV1Adapter)

**First Trial**:
following rayTune doc https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/faq.html#how-can-i-use-large-datasets-in-tune

```
tuner = tune.Tuner(
    tune.with_resources(tune.with_parameters(
       train_model, ds_train=ds_train, ds_valid=ds_valid),
    resources={'cpu':1})
)

def train_model(config, ds_train, ds_valid):
    model = <simple deep learning model>
    history = model.fit(x=ds_train, validation_data=ds_valid)
    return history
```

This outputs `raytune tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentERror: Cannot convert a Tensor of dtype variant to a Numpy array`

**Second Trial** :
creating tf.data.dataset within train_model function works however it consumes more memory since each rayTune worker needs to generate tf.data.dataset leading to OOM error.

**Third Trial** :
Saved ds_train, ds_valid using `tf.data.experimentai.save(ds_train, path)` then within train_model allowed each rayTune worker to simple load tf.data.dataset then use it via `tf.data.experimental.load(path)`.

This removes benefit of `petastorm` which ses AWS S3 as source data for tf.data.Dataset therefore everytime size of tf.data.dataset increases, local disk size must increase as well.

What are some best practices to do distributed training using RayTune on tf.data.Dataset?